ArgumentError: assert_no_enqueued_jobs requires the Active Job test adapter, you're using ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter
We've been looking to upgrade to Rails 7.2.0 and we're getting a new error in MiniTest (v 5.24.1).
ArgumentError: assert_no_enqueued_jobs requires the Active Job test adapter, you're using ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter.

I can't see any notes in the Rails Changelog or open issues
Any suggestions on how to fix?

You have to set your adapter for test environment:
# config/environment/test.rb

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test



All tests now respect the active_job.queue_adapter config.
Previously if you had set config.active_job.queue_adapter in your config/application.rb or config/environments/test.rb file, the adapter you selected was previously not used consistently across all tests. In some tests your adapter would be used, but other tests would use the TestAdapter.
In Rails 7.2, all tests will respect the queue_adapter config if provided. If no config is provided, the TestAdapter will continue to be used.
See #48585 for more details.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.2.0/activejob/CHANGELOG.md#rails-720-august-09-2024

Note that if you'd previously defined your queue adapter in an initializer file (e.g. config/initializer/good_job.rb) then this line won't override the setting for your tests correctly. You need to define it in application.rb or production.rb and development.rb.
